# No bash, qual é a diferença entre <, << e <<<?

Tags: bash

Estou aprendo agora a mexer com `bash` (Terminal do Ubuntu) e gostaria de entender a diferença entre esses três operadores.

Acho que `<` está relacionado à arquivos, mas não sei explicar o que ele faz descritivamente. Acho que é para mandar o valor do arquivo para o comando a ser executado.

Exemplo:

```
cat < index.php
#Exibe o conteúdo do arquivo
```

Quando uso `<<`, fica abrindo uma nova linha, sem executar o comando anterior (não entendi o que ele faz direito).

Exemplo:

```
cat <<
>
>
```

E o `<<<` me pareceu estar relacionado à expressões.

Exemplo:

```
cat <<< "O número é $((13 + 2))"
O número é 15
```

- Então, em qual caso uso `<`, `<<`, ou `<<<`?
- Qual é a finalidade de cada um?
- Como se chamam?

Comment: Relacionado a [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators). Tem outros bem interessantes também, como `<>`.

Comment: segue os links, além de uma ótima explicação ainda contém exemplos [Here Documents](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/here-docs.html) [Here Strings](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html) [I/O Redirection](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/io-redirection.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## `<` Redirecionamento de entrada

Para comandos que esperam por uma entrada (normalmente teclado), você pode redirecionar um arquivo para a entrada (assim como você fez com o `cat < index.php`). Outro exemplo:

```
nc -l 8888 < /etc/fstab
```

## `<<` Redirecionamento de entrada de string

É a mesma coisa, porém ao invés de passar um arquivo, você digita diretamente a string (em múltiplas linhas). Você acaba a entrada com um <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> , ou da seguinte forma:

```
cat << FIM
bla bla
bla
FIM
```

Normalmente utilizado para imprimir mensagens na tela com indentação.

## `<<<`

Não consegui achar uma definição para isso, mas uso como um redirecionador da saída de um comando, como se fosse um *pipe* invertido. Exemplo:

```
grep -i label <<< cat /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Esse exemplo do `<< ` me lembra muito o `HereDoc Syntax` do PHP

Comment: @WallaceMaxters em bash tem o "Here Document" (`<<EOF`) também, o PHP provavelmente se "inspirou" nessa parte assim como outras em coisas além do C, não conheço a história de decisões por trás do PHP :), só estou supondo. PS: o `<<<` se chama "Here String", assim como o `<<` se chama "Here doc" e o "Tab Suppression" (`<<-`, com o hífen) se eu não me engano apara espaçamentos no 'começo de linhas'. Depois vou testar, pq são coisas que usei muito pouco só pra confirmar se não confundi algo.

Answer (score 6):

Basicamente:

**`<`** - Operador de entrada, o comando antecedente recebe o que for passado apos o '<';

**`<<`** - Operador de entrada, com append, você pode usar para mais de uma linha de entrada. Não vejo muita utilidade;

Paras as saídas idem
**`>`** - Operador de saída, a saída será direcionada para o que estiver a frente do '>'
*Note que, em Linux, tudo são arquivos, então, se você deseja que a saída de um comando seja direcionada direto para uma tela auxiliar, você pode usar este comando, veja [isso](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com.br/2011/12/send-output-from-one-terminal-to.html), apenas um exemplo.*

**`>>`** - Saída com append, quer dizer que se a saída for para um arquivo, o mesmo será incrementado com a saída atual.

Já o outro operador, **`<<<`**, não vi muita utilidade, mas seria utilizado para ler entradas em string.

- [A wikipedia cita isso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29).
- Este outro [artigo](https://web.archive.org/web/20150222040932/http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/02/linuxunix-redirection-operatorsfile-descriptors-explained-examples.html) é mais informativo.
- E para quem está começando com o `bash`, vale a pena ver [este](http://wiki.ubuntu-br.org/ComandosBasicos).

Comment: Acho que faltou só o `<<<`

Comment: Na verdade inverti ali, mas ja vou editar. Mas veja que o comantário do @Dherik acima esclarece todos os pontos.

Comment: @CelsoMarigoJr, coloque mais algumas informações destes operadores e até com um exemplo de cada. Aí a sua resposta fica melhor ainda. Eu, pessoalmente,  gosto de algo mais sucinto, mas não sei o que o Wallace espera :)

Comment: @Dherik, vou postar alguns exemplos!

Answer (score 4):

- `<` é o redirecionador de entrada, envia um arquivo para a entrada padrão (stdin) do comando
- `<<` se chama "here documents", em geral é usado para escrever uma string *inline* no script e enviar ela para a stdin do comando. A string se encerra pelo token que segue o << aparecendo sozinho no início de uma linha:

  $ xargs ls <<FIN

  /tmp

  FIN
- `<<<` se chama "here strings", expande a expressão que segue o operador e a envia para a stdin do comando

Obs.: o exemplo do operador `<<<` dado pelo @cemdorst não é bom, ele funciona porque apenas a expressão imediatamente após o operador (no caso do exemplo, o `cat`) é passado como stdin do `grep`, o nome `/etc/fstab` é passado como argumento normal para o `grep`.

Há algumas variações, a documentação deles é bem descrita na *manpage* do bash (procure "Here Documents", "Here Strings").

Basicamente a utilidade deles é passar texto para a stdin de outros comandos, já que nisso (processamento de texto recebido via stdin) se baseia muito da programação em shellscript. Sem o "here documents" por exemplo, seria necessário usar comandos `echo` mais xaropes, ou criar arquivos externos extras além do script que se estiver escrevendo.